# how to use getKeyChar in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

In Class Controller(javafx)

```
@FXML
private void check (ActionEvent evt)
{

    if( Character.isDigit( evt.getKeyChar() ) )
    {

    }

    else
    {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }

}
```

> (TextField  On Action = check)

This episode `getKeyChar()` was error!

Comment: Please state more clearly what the problem is, what is the expected output, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Only accept text  in TextField .

Comment: Number does not accept

Comment: What is the significance of "(TextField On Action = check)" - I don't think I understand the problem here. What error are you getting?

Comment: Error : Cannot Resolve Method